# How to escape \t (tabs) from Github Action?

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a Github step where it runs a command and multiple lines are returned with some tabbing as well for formatting.

My problem is when I capture the output of the command I'm able to escape the \n and \r, but can't find a way of escaping \t ?

Example

```
- name: Run command
  id: my_command
  run: |
    content="mycommand_to_run"
    content="${content//'%'/'%25'}"
    content="${content//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
    content="${content//$'\r'/'%0D'}"
    echo "::set-output name=result_command::$content"
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to escape tab with:

```
content="${content//$'\t'/'%09'}"
```